# bad request for field slot 0 -1. numRows= 10, numColumn = 1

Tags: android, sql, listview

I have an activity that shows the results of a search (in my database) in a  two listview. The problem is that the application always crashes every time I run the apps. This is what the logcat shows me :

```
07-02 12:42:15.940: E/CursorWindow(23645): Bad request for field slot 0,1. numRows = 10, numColumns = 1
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.series3/com.example.series3.FindMePlace}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 1 failed
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 1 failed
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at com.example.series3.DatabaseHandler.getAllFromLocation(DatabaseHandler.java:737)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at com.example.series3.FindMePlace.populateFromLocation(FindMePlace.java:108)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at com.example.series3.FindMePlace.onCreate(FindMePlace.java:53)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-02 12:42:15.980: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

here is part of my code.

**FindMePlace.java**

```
    private void populateToDestination() {
            List<UkmRoute> destination = db.getAllToDestination();
            for (UkmRoute k : destination) {
                results.add(k.getToDestination());
                results_id.add(k.getID());
            }
            if (!filterText2.getText().toString().equals(""))
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMePlace.this,
                        R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, results);
            else {
                ArrayList<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMePlace.this,
                        R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, r);
            }
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            // Set ListView from ListActivity
            ListView lv2 = getListView();
            lv2.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            // Set click event from listView
            lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.d("test", "position:" + position);

                    Log.d("test",
                            "actualname:"
                                    + db.getUkmRouteByTo(adapter.getItem(position))
                                            .getFromLocation());

                    // String poiID = results_id.get(position);
                    String poiID = db.getUkmRouteByTo(adapter.getItem(position))
                            .getID();
                    setSelectedPoi(poiID);
                    // startActivity(c);

                }
            });

        }
private void populateFromLocation() {
        // Reading location
        Log.d("Reading", "Reading all location ..");
        List<UkmRoute> location = db.getAllFromLocation();

        for (UkmRoute k : location) {
            results.add(k.getFromLocation());
            results_id.add(k.getID());
        }
        // Set list arrayAdapter to adapter
        if (!filterText.getText().toString().equals(""))
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMePlace.this,
                    R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, results);
        else {
            ArrayList<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMePlace.this,
                    R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, r);
        }

        // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
        // R.id.textView1, results);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // Set ListView from ListActivity
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.d("test", "position:" + position);

                Log.d("test",
                        "actualname:"
                                + db.getUkmRouteByFrom(
                                        adapter.getItem(position))
                                        .getFromLocation());

                // String poiID = results_id.get(position);
                String poiID = db.getUkmRouteByFrom(adapter.getItem(position))
                        .getID();
                setSelectedPoi(poiID);
                // startActivity(c);

            }
        });
    }
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public List<UkmRoute> getAllToDestination() {
        List<UkmRoute> ToList = new ArrayList<UkmRoute>();
        //Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT ToDestination FROM " + TABLE_UKMROUTE; 

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UkmRoute poi = new UkmRoute();
                poi.setID(cursor.getString(0));
                poi.setFromLocation(cursor.getString(1));
                poi.setToDestination(cursor.getString(2));
                poi.setRoute1(cursor.getString(3));
                poi.setRoute2(cursor.getString(4));
                //Adding kategori to list
                ToList.add(poi);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return Kategori list
        return ToList;
    }
        public List<UkmRoute> getAllFromLocation() {
            List<UkmRoute> ToList = new ArrayList<UkmRoute>();
            //Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT FromLocation FROM " + TABLE_UKMROUTE; 

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            //looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    UkmRoute poi = new UkmRoute();
                    poi.setID(cursor.getString(0));
                    poi.setFromLocation(cursor.getString(1));
                    poi.setToDestination(cursor.getString(2));
                    poi.setRoute1(cursor.getString(3));
                    poi.setRoute2(cursor.getString(4));
                    //Adding kategori to list
                    ToList.add(poi);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // return Kategori list
            return ToList;
            }
```

is there anything wrong with my sql query?

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT ToDestination FROM " + TABLE_UKMROUTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have only one column in your query `ToDestination`.
But you try to get the information from more than one column:

```
poi.setID(cursor.getString(0));
            poi.setFromLocation(cursor.getString(1));
            poi.setToDestination(cursor.getString(2));
            poi.setRoute1(cursor.getString(3));
            poi.setRoute2(cursor.getString(4));
```

try this:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT ID, FromLocation, ToDestination, Route1, Route2 FROM " + TABLE_UKMROUTE;
```

or

```
    "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_UKMROUTE;
```

and

```
poi.setID(cursor.getInteger("ID")); // getInteger only if ID is an Integer
            poi.setFromLocation(cursor.getString("FromLocation"));
            poi.setToDestination(cursor.getString("ToDestination"));
            poi.setRoute1(cursor.getString("Route1"));
            poi.setRoute2(cursor.getString("Route2"));
```

Comment: no. this is part of my coding. i also include the another one inside my code.

Comment: the sql in inside the DatabaseHandler.java

Comment: from the query that you post, do i need to mention all the column? i just want the listview show "ToDestination" only. and another listview show FromLocation only

Comment: It cannot work. also with your update. You set one column in your sql. The result is a cursor with only one column. In this case ToDestination. If you try to get the information of column 1, 2, 3 and 4 it must fail.

Comment: Split the functionality of load the bussinesobjects and display the information. First of all load the objects. After that you can decide to show only one attribute of each object.

Comment: due to i'm still new in programming field especially in android,i'm not really clear what am i suppose to do. what do you mean by "Split the functionality of load the bussinesobjects"?

Comment: see my update. that shoult be enough. at least to solve the error in your question.

Comment: becouse some of your database fields were no String's. What type is FromLocation and ToDestination? Long, Integer???

Comment: all string. there's no Long n Integer

Comment: than change this cursor.getInteger to this cursor.getString